# sqlite fts quoting problem

Tags: bash, command-line, quoting, sqlite

I can do this in sqlite tool:

```
sqlite> select caption  from notes_fts where notes_fts MATCH '"perl install"';
```

but cannot from the Linux shell i.e., this fails:

```
user@host:~$ sqlite3 sqldb  "select caption  from notes_fts where notes_fts MATCH '"it perl install  "';"
```

I tried different versions of quoting `"` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
sqlite3 sqldb "select caption from notes_fts where notes_fts MATCH '\"perl install\"';"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
sqlite3 sqldb "select caption from notes_fts where notes_fts MATCH 'perl install';"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work as it does not have the exact matching restriction of the additional quotes i.e. if it works, the result should be an exact match e.g. 
UNIX My Install
Your solution results in multiple inexact matches e.g. .cshrc
Admin
UNIX My Install
1 Liners
cpan